# Added CyberStride 'Contact Form' - no 'New -> Contact Page' option added?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm following the book 'O'Reilly Orchard CMS Up and Running' - page 28.

It states that if you add the CyberStride 'Contact Form' module, an option should appear under 'New -> Contact Page' in the left navigation.

So I go to Modules/Gallery/[search for 'contact']
'Install' 'Contact Form' from CyberStride

but nothing is added:

[image: new navigation]

This didn't appear - is the book wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Otherwise, impressed with Orchard.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module is pretty old, I don't think it is compatible with the latest source code.

Try this module: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.PlanetTelex.ContactForm, this is newer and works with the latest source code I believe.

Or try using the CustomForms module to create a contact form, see here for a tutorial: http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha

Comment: thanks - I've installed and enabled 'contact form'. How do I add it to the site?

Comment: Think Ive got it. Content / Content Types / Contact Form Widget / Edit / Creatable - adds an item under 'New' on nav.

Comment: actually how do I put the widget on a contact us page - not really clear?! (Im still new to Orchard). 'New Contact Form Widget' - just takes me to a widgets page where I can place the form directly on a layer - I want it on a contact us page only?!

Comment: +1 for suggesting Custom Forms--no need to use a 3rd party module for something 1.6 already supports.

Comment: Custom forms are the way to go. Very flexible, but not obvious how to set up. I answered a SO question on setting up custom forms that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648521/31569